# Flask and ZMQ socket can't send data in route

Tags: python, flask, pyzmq

I try to send Data with a ZMQ.socket it work , but in a FLASK route, the message is not sended. The socket is open I see her in netstat, but if I make a `tcpdump -i 4999` I have nothing.
I use Uwsgi with Nginx and FLASK.

code sample

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session,redirect,url_for, jsonify, json
import zmq
import time
import uwsgi

my_app_name=Flask(__name__)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444")
time.sleep(0.5)
socket.send_string("message") # OK

@my_app_name.route('/')
def index():
  socket.send_string("message") # not OK
  return ("don't work")
```

FLASK  or ZMQ say nothing  don't have error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have add "single-interpreter = true" in my my_app_name.ini and it work